# concurrent hashmap segmentation

Tags: java, concurrency

The [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#ConcurrentHashMap.Segment) says  by default we have 16 segments in concurrenthashmap so 16 thread can modify at a time. similarly if only one thread is there then it mean we should have only one segment . Then the entire CHM will be locked when the update operation is carried out. Wouldnt it be better to have larger number of segments everytime we use a concurrenthashmap as it will help other reader threads to get the value.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Do you mean that you have more than 16 threads concurrently modifying the hashmap, and that you wonder if more than 16 segments would be a good idea in this case?

Comment: i mean even if we have only 1 writer thread, shouldnt we have larger number of segments, as it will only help the other reader threads to get the data

Comment: It's a trade-off: the more segments, the larger the internal overhead. You have to balance this against the gains you are hoping for.

Comment: Get operations do not block, and are done in parallel with writes. In any case, you shouldn't try to optimize unless you have a performance problem and you've measured that it is caused by the map.

Comment: Besides, the the "concurrency level" of a `ConcurrentHashMap` is a [tuneable parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#ConcurrentHashMap-int-float-int-).